Symfony (7.1.3) Curl error: "operation aborted by callback" when using vdocipher API
I'm facing an issue with curl where I receive the error message operation aborted by callback when trying to send a video to vdocipher's server using POST requests. Below are the relevant methods and their details:

createVideo:

public function createVideo($filePath, $fileMimeType, $fileName)
    {
        $title = md5(time() . uniqid() . $fileName);
        $this->urlAction = "?title={$title}";
        
        $videoResponse = $this->sendDataVdocipher("PUT");
        
        if (empty($videoResponse->clientPayload)) {
            return null;
        }
        
        $credentials = $videoResponse->clientPayload;

        $data = [
            'policy' => $credentials->policy,
            'key' => $credentials->key,
            'x-amz-signature' => $credentials->{'x-amz-signature'},
            'x-amz-algorithm' => $credentials->{'x-amz-algorithm'},
            'x-amz-date' => $credentials->{'x-amz-date'},
            'x-amz-credential' => $credentials->{'x-amz-credential'},
            'success_action_status' => 201,
            'success_action_redirect' => '',
            'file' => new CURLFile($filePath, $fileMimeType, $fileName),
        ];

        $uploadResponse = $this->sendDataVdocipher(
            'POST',
            $data,
            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
            $credentials->uploadLink,
            false
        );

        if (!$uploadResponse) {
            $this->deleteVideo($videoResponse->videoId);

            return null;
        }

        return $videoResponse->videoId;
    }


sendDataVdocipher:

protected function sendDataVdocipher(
        $method = "GET",
        $data = null,
        $header = "Content-Type: application/json",
        $url = null,
        $allHeaders = true
    ) {
        if (empty($url)) {
            $url = $this->url . $this->urlAction;
        }

        if (empty($header)) {
            $header = "Content-Type: application/json";
        }

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);

        $headers = [$header];

        if ($allHeaders) {
            $headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
            $headers[] = "Authorization: Apisecret {$this->token}";
        }

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

        if ($method == "POST" || $method == "PUT") {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        }

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $error = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if ($error) {
            return null;
        }

        $responseObj = json_decode($response);

        return $responseObj ?? true;
    }

CURLOPT_VERBOSE logs:
*   Trying 108.139.168.232:443...

* Connected to vdo-us-east.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com (108.139.168.232) port 443 (#0)

* ALPN, offering h2

* ALPN, offering http/1.1

*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs

* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol

* Server certificate:

*  subject: CN=*.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com

*  start date: Dec 19 00:00:00 2023 GMT

*  expire date: Dec  2 23:59:59 2024 GMT

*  subjectAltName: host "vdo-us-east.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "*.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com"

*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M01

*  SSL certificate verify ok.

> POST / HTTP/1.1

Host: vdo-us-east.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com

Accept: */*

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------c50e1976b4166e97

Expect: 100-continue


* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse

< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

* operation aborted by callback

* Closing connection 0


The error occurs when sending a POST request by calling the createVideo method, which also uses the sendDataVdocipher method to send PUT requests in order to obtain the upload credentials (as described in the API documentation).
What I’ve tried:

Verified that the URL, headers, and data for the curl requests are correctly configured.
Checked that the CURLFile instance is created properly for file uploads.
Ensured that the API token and endpoint URLs are valid.


This is a CURL_READFUNC_ABORT error and can arise in a handful of cases in both cURL and the PHP cURL extension. Some hints from curl_mime_data_cb would direct me to either your file being unreadable (unstreamable) or something wrong with the mime type. Is the file actually readable (if it's an uploaded file it may not be immediately usable unless moved via move_uploaded_file). Any errors in the logs? Can you add CURLOPT_VERBOSE and save input and output to a log file, please?

Sure, I've edited the question and added the verbose logs. And just to clarify, the possibility of the file being unreadable came into my mind too, so I've tried to upload it directly into aws s3 servers, and it worked perfectly, which eliminate any possibility of error with the file itself.

I've tested your code and was able to upload all the videos without any issues. Environment: PHP 8.3.9 (cli) (built: Jul  2 2024 14:10:14) (NTS), curl 8.6.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin23.0) libcurl/8.6.0 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.6 zlib/1.2.12 nghttp2/1.61.0. What versions are you using? php -v, curl --version and what platform?

Sample video that I uploaded https://player.vdocipher.com/v2/?otp=20160313versUSE323p2U3Yxo8pQUcNVxRb4CezJXwajaeu9LB925FRSz87kut4k&playbackInfo=eyJ2aWRlb0lkIjoiYjk0NWRjNGFhNzYxNDg1MTljNjJmM2Y4YmFkMDU1OTAifQ==

Eureka! I was able to reproduce "operation aborted by callback" when I passed in a non-existent file, however. So my initial guess was correct. You can try to check the passed in file using is_readable and throw an exception to make sure that it's actually readable.

Nice! I've tested the file using the is_readable method as you suggested and got true as output, proving that the file is indeed readable. And, as I said before, I've successfully uploaded it into aws s3 servers without any trouble. The only difference from your environment to mine is the curl version. I've just ran an sudo apt upgrade curl and now I'm at version 7.81. Could that be causing the problem?

Link for aws s3 video: https://testeeadpublic.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/club/1/course/lesson/documents/7ee7e04edf455e0ce015d6afe6a35b57_dummy-videomp4.mp4

Oh, and I'm also using WSL 2 with ubuntu 22.04 in my environment.
